# What is the range of AVCaptureDevice torchLevel in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, torch, avcapturedevice

I am working in an app that scans QR Codes and to improve reading in very low light conditions, besides configuring the `automaticallyEnablesLowLightBoostWhenAvailable`, and trying `setExposureModeCustom(duration:, iso:)`  I am setting the camera flash as a low intensity torch using `setTorchModeOn(level:)` method

I tested in the 0.1-1.0 range and it works fine, and I wanted to find out the max value for this setting using `AVCaptureDevice.maxAvailableTorchLevel` and the result I get is the following:

```
do {
    try captureDevice.lockForConfiguration()
    print("Max Torch: \(AVCaptureDevice.maxAvailableTorchLevel)")
    captureDevice.unlockForConfiguration()
} catch {
    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Max Torch: 3.40282e+38

Anyone knows what does this value mean?   It is not meant to emit light like the sun's surface    :)

... e

Comment: I would assume that is the value when the device has no torch (like the Simulator.)

Comment: That's the value of `Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude`. The documentation for `maxAvailableTorchLevel` says *"This constant always represents the maximum available torch level, independent of the actual maximum value currently supported by the device."*.